# Perturbing metrics with nonpositive curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact $3$-dimensional manifold diffeomorphic to a ball. Suppose that $M$ has nonpositive (sectional) curvature and its boundary $\partial M$ is convex, or even that  $M$ is a Riemannian ball, i.e., $\partial M$ is equidistant from a point in $M$. Is it possible to make the curvature negative everywhere by a $C^2$ perturbation of the metric?

**Note:** This does not seem possible in dimension $2$. Consider for instance the [Monkey saddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_saddle), which has an isolated point of zero curvature. This point happens to be a branch point of the Gauss map. Hence it cannot be removed by a perturbation of the surface. But I am not sure if all perturbations of the metric here correspond to a perturbation of the surface in $R^3$, or even admit an isometric embedding in $R^3$.

Comment: What do you mean by convexity if $M$ in general? Do you mean convex boundary? Also, do you mean that $M$ is connected with nonempty boundary?

Comment: @Kohan: yes, convex boundary. Yes, connected with nonempty boundary.

Comment: You’re allowing the metric be perturbed at the boundary too?

Comment: @Deane Yang: yes, the metric may be perturbed at the boundary.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, it is not known whether any perturbation of the saddle surface metric can be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$. It’s a hyperbolic Monge-Ampère PDE, so it’s possible that it is.

Comment: It seems that the note is not relevant to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a strongly convex function $f\colon M\to \mathbb{R}$;
you can take $f=\mathrm{dist}_p^2$.
Consider the product $M\times (-\mathbb R)$ (this is a space-time manifold).
Observe that, for small $\varepsilon>0$, the graph of $\varepsilon\cdot f$ with the induced metric from $M\times (-\mathbb R)$ has strictly negative curvature.

Convexity of boundary should hold for small $\varepsilon$, assuming that the boundary was strongly convex;
the latter holds for balls.